# C++ - Design different classes to be able to exchange their rule

Tags: c++

There is a design issue I need your help with.

Suppose I need to design a clothing store.  In this store there are Sellers and Buyers each one is registered in the shop with an ID.

**We want to allow a Seller to sign in as a Buyer and vice versa (using the same ID he was originally signed up with).**

Keep in mind that Buyer and Seller have different data memeber and also in order to use the function Buy all we need is the Buyer data member and not he Seller data member.

At first sight, while considering that the Seller has different data member from the Buyer I decided to set these two classes as derived of ShopPerson which is derived from Person.

The reason I decided to have ShopPerson class is to allow Buyer and Seller a base class containing common functions .( becuase both of them can Buy and Sell)

***My problem is:***

The "Buy" function should be only member of Buyer, but then how could I treat a Seller as a Buyer? If by chance the Buyer is a Seller than he won't have this function.

My solution above, using a ShopPerson class to have a shared/common classes isn't good either because the Buy function uses some data member which are only **dedicated for the Buyer** and the ShopPerson wouldn't be familiar with them.

The only solution I have in mind is to drop of inheritance, but I am not sure if this is correct.
How can I solve this design issue? Any ideas?

Thank you all, Syndicator!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance may not be what you need. Perhaps something like the below.

```
class Buyer{
    ShopPerson* person;

    void Buy();
};


class Seller{
    ShopPerson* person;

    void Sell();
};
```

i.e You have a central list of `ShopPerson`, but `Buyer` and `Seller` are thin classes which are instantiated on a transaction by transaction basis. You could use inheritance now

```
class TransactionParticipant{
     ShopPerson *person;
     //Misc common functionality
};
```

And inherit `Buyer` and `Seller` from this class.

Comment: But how can a seller become a buyer then?

Comment: Yes. Consider that a function would need to get as a parameter just a ShopPerson and let him Sell and Buy, showhow :)

Comment: @ArneMertz Seller and buyer would just exist for that transaction. Next transaction, the same ShopPerson would be a seller or a buyer if he pleases.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB id would be linked to `ShopPerson` if they want to sign in as `Buyer` instanciate a `Buyer`, else a `Seller`.

Comment: So both Seller and Buyer don't need the dm "ShopPerson* person;" if they inherit from TransactionParticipant, right? Also is this pattern is called "Adapter"?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB yup you are right, you dont need the common pointer any more. And it does look like the Adaptor pattern, but I believe the intent is different. Adaptor sounds like more of a compatibility aid.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm trying to digest it =]

Comment: +1 … this is a specific case of the more general [envelope–letter pattern](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/cpp/envelope/).

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit from if *every* seller is a buyer as well, or if only some sellers can be a buyer. In the first case, it's easy: a seller *is a* buyer, that means plain inheritance: `class Seller : public Buyer`

In the second case, each ShopPerson should have a buyer behavior, I would consider something like this:

```
struct BuyerBehavior
{
  void buy();
  string creditCardNumer(); 
  //and so on
};

class ShopPerson
{
public:
  BuyerBehavior* getBuyerBehavior();
};

class Seller : public ShopPerson
{
  // some seller-specific stuff here
};
```

A seller could accuire a buyer behavior - and in order to buy something, he must have that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer by Karthik T, you can do this so you can convert between types as appropriate:

```
class ShopPerson {
   // Common data
   // Optional data:
   unique_ptr<BuyerData> buyer_data; 
   unique_ptr<SellerData> seller_data; 

public:
   shared_ptr<Buyer> buyerPersonality(); // return null ptr, if no buyer data
   shared_ptr<Seller> sellerPersonality(); // return null ptr, if no seller data
};

class Buyer {
   shared_ptr<ShopPerson> person;
   BuyerData* buyer_data; // Points to person->buyer_data
public:
   void buy();
};

class Seller {
   shared_ptr<ShopPerson> person;
   SellerData* seller_data; // Points to person->seller_data
public:
   void sell();
};
```

Comment: Looks good, just one thing. Regarding the function "shared_ptr<Seller> sellerPersonality()" - you must have a data member Seller* in order to know what pointer to return, am I right?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB `sellerPersonality()` I think would create a Seller object based on `SellerData` and `ShopPerson` members

Comment: +1 keeps track of persistant buyer/seller data between transactions

Comment: @KarthikT - I'm sorry for the ignorance but wouldn't it be better in this case that the Seller and the Buyer would inherit from ShopPerson and then they wouldn't need to hold the seller_data and buyer_data which is already defined in the base class (ShopPerson)

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB The problem with the inheritance is the original one, you cant change a buyer to a seller any more..

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: it depends. If you need object identity for `Seller`, you probably need a data member of type `weak_ptr<Seller>` to remember the last seller handed out. If you don't need that, you can create a new `Seller` every time - or even make Seller a handle class with value semantics (i.e. return `Seller` ratther than `shared_ptr<Seller>`). Similarly for Buyer of course.

Comment: @Karthik T: In this design, if you make the relation from `Buyer` back to its `ShopPerson` navigable, you can get from `Buyer` to `ShopPerson` to `Seller` (same for the other direction). If it takes extra steps to enable the seller or buyer personalities (extra login, provide more personal data) that code would operate on the `ShopPerson` until the preconditions are met.

Comment: @JoergB Do you mean if ShopPerson were the base class of Buyer and Seller as OP was asking? In that case, you could make a buyer a seller, but that would involve copying the base ShopPerson, since it is a different object.

Comment: @Karthik T: I would not make `ShopPerson` a base class, unless all of `Buyer`, `Seller` and `ShopPerson` are handle classes (value-semantics) that share a common data (and implementation primitive) class via `shared_ptr<ShopPersonImpl>`. If you want object identity, inheritance is bad for that very reason: if you have both a `Buyer` and a `Seller` for the same person, you now have two `ShopPerson` instances for the same person (violating the intended object identity).

Comment: @JoergB Then I fail to see your original point, I assumed you were supporting the OPs point. This design and my own original ones both do support accessing the `ShopPerson` from `Buyer` and `Seller` for the express reason of switching one to the other

Comment: Thank you very much - This discussion helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something fitted for the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). You have some shop people that under certain conditions are extended to either sellers or buyers. Of course, the decoration (extension) is performed at runtime, based on the role they logon with.

Comment: Isnt the decorator pattern meant for situations where the interface remains the same but the behavior changes? Here there is an interface change as well.

Comment: @KarthikT no, the decorator is about *adding* behavior, not *changing* it, since the decorator routes calls through to the decorated object before or after its own implementation. A decorator may provide additional behavior via additional methods in the interface as well. This would be somewhat similar to your own suggestion, if you TransactionParticipant was indeed a ShopPerson itself.